# How to deal with a minion "already deleted from tracker"?

Tags: salt-stack

When running

```
salt '*' test.ping -s --out json
```

I get the following output (reduced to just a few typical cases, the ellipsis covers the same cases)

```
Minion sent222 did not respond. No job will be sent.
(...)
minion sent005 was already deleted from tracker, probably a duplicate key
(...)
{
(...)
    "sent005": true,
(...)
}
```

The case of `sent222` is clear: it is not available.

What should I do with `sent002`? It does answer, but also warns about being deleted from the tracker and having a duplicate key. **What does this mean?**

I noticed this by chance because the regular `salt '*' test.ping` simply states that `sent005` is `True`, without any further comments on its state.